# Cassandra removing node : is it possible to stop decommission and lauch removenode?

Tags: cassandra

I have an issue with a cassandra node on a 10 nodes cluster.
I first launched a decommission on that node to remove it from the cluster.
The decommission is currently active but the load on this node is such that it takes an infinite time and I would like to go faster.

What I thought to do was to stop this node and launch a `removenode` from another one.
The DataStax documentation explains that we should use `decommission` or `removenode` depending on the up/down status of the node. But there is no information about `removenode` while targeted node has already leaving status.

So my question is: Is it possible to launch a `removenode` of a stopped node while this one has already a leaving status?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So my question is: Is it possible to launch a `removenode` of a stopped node while this one has already a leaving status?

I had to do this last week, so "yes" it is possible.

Just be careful, though.  At the time, I was working on bringing up a new DC in a non-production environment, so I didn't care about losing the data that was on the node (or in the DC, for that matter).

> What I thought to do was to stop this node and launch a `removenode` from another one.

You can do exactly that.  Get the Host ID of the node you want to drop, and run:

```
$ nodetool removenode 2e143c2b-0571-4c5d-22d5-9a2668648710
```

And if that gets stuck, <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> out of it, and (on the same node) you can run:

```
$ nodetool removenode force
```

Answer (score 0):

Decommissioning a node in Cassandra can only be stopped , if that node is restarted .
Its status will change from **UL** to **UN** .
This approach is tested and cassandra cluster worked well afterwards.

Following this safe approach , trigger nodetool remove for consistent data.